# CSS - Make a background that is half-transparent, half-image

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I need to make a background for a block which will consist of two equal parts: the top part should be transparent, and the bottom part should be filled with a pattern. Exact height of the block is unknown. And I can't use `no-repeat` because inside the bottom part, image should be repeated as many times as needed to fill it.

Is it all possible?

(It would be great, for example, to make a linear-gradient from full transparency to the image background, but as far as I understand there is no such thing.)

Here's what I want, approximately: https://maaaks.ru/images/screens/rect4140.png

Comment: Something like this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp ?

Comment: No. I need one of parts to be an image. I added a picture of how it should look like.

Comment: Well, after some trying, I solved my problem with SVG.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use a positioned pseudo-element like so:

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-25-25-4.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil minus sed magnam, sint nam nisi aut ad consequuntur corrupti assumenda, aliquid doloremque modi voluptatem ex!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could position an absolute div below the actual content, which you divide in two parts: One transparent and one with the image.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="background">
        <div class="transparent"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
         Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

Position wrapper and content relative. Let wrapper float, and let .content float in wrapper. This way wrapper will stretch with content. Now you can position background absolute, with top, bottom, left and right 0. The rest is easy.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To an extent this does the trick in css:

```
.imageDiv{
    padding-top:50%;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

Obviously putting text in the top half can't be applied directly in this div, but it was enough for what I was doing. To get text in the top half, the easiest solution it seems would be to have a container div and two inner divs, one for the image, the other for the text. Then make the inner divs overlay on top of each other by applying css postion absolute and stretch them to the entire dimensions of the container with left,right,top,bottom=0;